# Prove, that the product of $3$, and $4$ following natural numbers can never be a number with the form of $x^k$

Tags: number-theory

Prove, that the product of $3$, and $4$ following natural numbers can never be a number with the form of $x^k$ , where $x$ and $k$ are  natural numbers, and $k>1$ (for example $9$ has this form, because it's $3^2$ , but $10$ doesn't have this form).

I tried to write them down as $n-1$ , $n$ , $n+1$ , so we get $(n^2-n)(n+1)$, which is $(n^3-n^2+n^2-n)=(n^3-n)$ , but can't really go further with this, same, if we have $4$ numbers.

Comment: You should at least require that $k>1,$ otherwise your statement is trivially false.

Comment: Sorry, that is true. :) Yeah, k>1

Comment: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266042/product-of-three-consecutive-positive-integers-is-never-a-perfect-power) and a comment by a user marty cohen.

Comment: I remember seeing quite some time one (not easy) proof that no product of consecutive integers can be a perfect power.